# Remove only columns with NA by row

Tags: r, row, na

I am trying to avoid copy/pasting as there are a lot of data points, but I'm stuck on how to get there. I need to go through each row and remove the columns with NA. The problem is that the NA columns all differ by row.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L),
           pdc_5 = c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),
           pdc_67 = c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           pdc_30 = c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA),
           pdc_34 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           pdc_1 = c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA))

dat |> filter(id == "1") |> select_if(~all(!is.na(.)))
dat |> filter(id == "2") |> select_if(~all(!is.na(.)))
```

Desired results:

```
  id pdc_1
1  1   1

  id oxa_488 pdc_30
1  2     1    1
```

I tried `apply` with no avail.

```
apply(dat, 1, select_if(all(!is.na(dat))))

Error in is_logical(.predicate) : 
  argument ".predicate" is missing, with no default
```

Any thoughts? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the structure you are trying to create? In a data.frame all rows must have the same number of columns. Are you trying to create a list of data.frames with one row each? Maybe `dat |> split(~id) |> lapply(function(x) x[, !is.na(x), drop=F])` would work?

Comment: perhaps a non-issue, but where you your values of `100` come from?

Comment: looks like I copied the output from the previous code and not the code that created the example dataset, i'll edit for clarity - good catch